# Statistics based on a key

Tags: sql-server

What I'm looking to do is to get some meta-data "stats" for my database for each table based on an ID which prevails throughout the database.

For example, if I have `customerId` key on almost all tables throughout the database, I'd like to run a query which tells me things like

- Number of rows in each table based on that ID
- Amount of space taken in each table based on that ID

I'm sure I could write a stored procedure which iterates over each table and looks for that Id and runs a separate query on each to gather row count, but is it possible to do it for space, or is there something built into SQL Server to get this information?

In the end, I'd probably build a table which reports on this information on a weekly or monthly basis so I can see trends of usage of each customer.

I'm looking at SQL Server 2017 or higher if that matters.

Comment: Working out how much space a row consumes is a less trivial task. You'd have to, effectively, use `DATALENGTH` against each column, and that wouldn't include data stored in indexes or header data (such as for variable length data types). In short, it doesn't really make sense to work out the size of a *row*.

Comment: If I want to know how much space a particular customer is consuming, it certainly makes sense.

Comment: Sounds like a very complex operation. perhaps you can just get the space used per table (sp_spaceused) and then divide by number of rows per customer to get some sort of average value. It will likely be as much correct as the DATALENGTH method (ie. not super correct but better than a guess), unless you have a lot of very large LOB values

Comment: To you you think it makes sense, but in reality, it doesn't. If you're worried about how much clients are using up, then they should have separate environments so you can bill them appropriately.

Comment: One hacky way that springs to mind - not tried it - would be to `insert-select into temptable` for the desired customer Id, then checking space used on the temp table should give you the space required for all rows for that Id. Depending on your data distriution that may or may not be practicle.

Comment: @ThomA Not feasible, but thanks for the advice on what I should deem important.

Comment: @siggemannen That's a pretty good idea. None of the tables that matter have any variable length data types, so this should work.

Comment: With respect, I didn't say anything about importance, I stated about what makes sense. These are different things. I then offered an alternative idea, and you shot it down with a false accusation... I'll just leave with saying that this is likely an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info); perhaps if you share what X is, someone else might offer an idea.

Comment: Does it need to be incrediply precise? Is it sufficient to just use a proportion of the full table space?

Comment: @ThomA My point being is that you're trying to tell me what is important to me. What is important to me is to find out how much space in the DB each customer is taking, hence the question.

Comment: So, if you aren't trying to work out the amount of space each client is using (as you state that isn't the important thing here), what are you trying to achieve? That you state that isn't the important thing here only cements that this is an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/), so we really need to understand what X is here, as you're asking about Y.

Comment: Where do I state that space isn't important? I explicitly state the exact opposite "What is important to me is to find out how much space in the DB each customer is taking".

Comment: You keep telling me that I am telling you what's important; I never did that, so I can only infer that the thing you think I'm telling you is important is the storage your clients are using. That you have taken this stance with me means that I'm "incorrect"; your priority or what you are trying to achieve isn't what am trying to help you with: identify the storage your clients are using. If that is the case, then I'm trying to understand what *is* important to you, as you imply storage space isn't with your stance towards me. If that is the important thing, your comments appear to conflict.

Comment: I want to know rows per client and space per client. Both are important. I never said otherwise anywhere else. You inferred incorrectly in your first reply when you said " In short, it doesn't really make sense to work out the size of a row. " . Yes, it does, when I want to know how much space each client is taking, unless you know of another way of solving the issue.

Comment: *" unless you know of another way of solving the issue"* I already stated this in a prior [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77856435/statistics-based-on-a-key?noredirect=1#comment137255944_77856435): *"If you're worried about how much clients are using up, then they should have separate environments so you can bill them appropriately"* When I made that suggesting you shot me down and accused me of not understanding the problem, but like I said, if knowing what the storage space each client is using is important, then that's one method

Comment: Then let me just add: Redesigning a system from the ground up isn't a valid solution in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code, which will construct a dynamic SQL query, that will add up the total `DATALENGTH` for every matching row in each table that has that column name.

It also takes into account clustered and non-clustered indexes. Do note that `DATALENGTH` is not a perfect representation of the size of indexes, for a number of reasons, but it should give you a good order-of-magnitude idea for each ID.

```sql
DECLARE @columnName sysname = 'id';
DECLARE @value int = 1;


DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

SELECT @sql = STRING_AGG(
  CONCAT(
    'SELECT
  TableName = ',
  QUOTENAME(t.name, ''''),
  ',
  DataSize = SUM(',
    c.Columns,
    ')
FROM ',
    QUOTENAME(s.name),
    '.',
    QUOTENAME(t.name),
    '
WHERE ',
    QUOTENAME(@columnName),
    ' = @value'
  ),
  '
UNION ALL
')
FROM sys.tables t
JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      Columns = STRING_AGG(CAST(
        CONCAT(
          'ISNULL(DATALENGTH(',
          QUOTENAME(c.name),
          '), 0) * ',
          i.CountColumnInIndex
        )
        AS nvarchar(max)), ' + ')
    FROM sys.columns c
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
          CountColumnInIndex =
            IIF(
              MAX(CASE WHEN i.index_id = 1 AND ic.index_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) = 1,
              COUNT(*),
              COUNT(CASE WHEN i.index_id <= 1 OR ic.index_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END)
            )
        FROM sys.indexes i
        LEFT JOIN sys.index_columns ic
          ON ic.index_id = i.index_id
         AND ic.object_id = t.object_id
         AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
        WHERE i.object_id = t.object_id
    ) i
    WHERE c.object_id = t.object_id
    GROUP BY ()
) c;

PRINT @sql; -- your friend

EXEC sp_executesql @sql,
  N'@value int',
  @value = @value;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/eM0znql4)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using @siggemannen idea of taking the total space in each table using the `sp_spaceused` sproc, and putting that in a temp table, along with the number of rows in the table, and dividing that out so I know space per row.

Since there is no variable length fields in any of the tables that I care about (there are some very small tables of insignificant size which do have variable length fields, and those are ignored), I then know the space per row.

Then it was a simple matter of iterating though each table, counting rows per customer, and doing a little arithmetic to find space used per customer for each table.

I expanded on the procedure with some optional variables, such as whether I wanted total space per customer in the database, or total space per customer per table, which also included a row count, and writing the appropriate queries to report back.

This allowed me to determine both "abuse" of certain modules by specific customers, and stray data per customer for modules which they no longer pay for, allowing for cleanup/archive of the data in question.